# IndentationError: expected an indented block help please

Tags: python

I have problem to run my python script
when I run it I got this message

```
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Here's my code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import hashlib
import sys

def main():
if len(sys.argv) < 2:

print "[ + ] Usage: %s <hash>" % sys.argv[0]

exit(0)

    commonStrings = [
        "Diaa",
        "Diab",
        "Mohammad",
        "test",
        "7amama",
        "sos",
        "lolo",
        "hacked",
        "try",
        "a_diaa_2007@yahoo.com",
        "secgeek",
        "lnxg33k",
        "diaa.diab.2012@gmail.com",
        "dia2diab@yandex.com",
        "dia2diab@yahoo.com"
        ]

    for i in commonStrings:
        if hashlib.md5(i).hexdigest() == sys.argv[1]:
        print "[ + ] OK i got it."
        print "[ + ] The hash value [ %s ] is the md5 of [ %s ]." % (sys.argv[1], i)
        exit(0)
    print "[ ! ] The hash not found on your own list."

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Yeah, you have a bunch of indentation issues.

Comment: The items after `hashlib.md5... sys.argv[1]:` should be indented I think.

Comment: can you help ? @MorganDarthKhanMegatron

Comment: Google "python indentation" and read about it.

Comment: The exception tells you which line has the problem... it would be helpful if you shared. You need to indent function bodies. That could be it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be the correct indentation.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import hashlib
import sys

def main():
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:    
        print "[ + ] Usage: %s <hash>" % sys.argv[0]   
        sys.exit(0)

    commonStrings = [
        "Diaa",
        "Diab",
        "Mohammad",
        "test",
        "7amama",
        "sos",
        "lolo",
        "hacked",
        "try",
        "a_diaa_2007@yahoo.com",
        "secgeek",
        "lnxg33k",
        "diaa.diab.2012@gmail.com",
        "dia2diab@yandex.com",
        "dia2diab@yahoo.com"
    ]

    for i in commonStrings:
        if hashlib.md5(i).hexdigest() == sys.argv[1]:
            print "[ + ] OK i got it."
            print "[ + ] The hash value [ %s ] is the md5 of [ %s ]." % (sys.argv[1], i)
            sys.exit(0)

    print "[ ! ] The hash not found on your own list."

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: @Editors Thank you for editing my answer!

Comment: also make sure that indentation type matches, meaning not just the amount of indentation (in a specific editor) butalso if it is spaces or tabs (which give different indentations in different editors), so better use pure-space indentations instead of tabs

Comment: @jgloves It wouldn't print of an indention area without the extra indention. just depends what the person is doing.

Comment: I used the indentation in python idle because I haven't read the indention rules for this site.

Comment: PEP8 recommends always using spaces over tabs and NEVER using mix.

Comment: @KurzedMetal not work

Comment: @KurzedMetal Thank you. I normally use pycharm and it does it for me, but I'll checl out the PEP8 document.

Comment: @AmeerAssadi what kind of error are you getting now?

Comment: My bad, my last edit missed an space, fixed.

Comment: @DeliriousMistakes i just got this [ + ] Usage: C:\Users\Ameer\Desktop\hb.py <hash>

Comment: @DeliriousMistakes Thanks it's work now

Comment: @KurzedMetal thank you !

Comment: Thank you to everyone who edited my answer.